# Import fbx file failure

Tags: import, .fbx

Total blender and general software noob. Trying to import an fbx rig into Blender. Keep getting the following error message:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MduH3.jpg

Model, rig, nothing will load in. All I need it for is to reparent a few bones and apply textures. Basically looking for how to get blender to recognize the fbx file or perhaps another program that may be easier than whatever is necessary to fix.

Comment: Please provide some additional information as to which version of blender you are using, the software the .FBX was exported with, system specs, etc. .

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.79, downloaded the FBX off of Sketchfab. Thing is, 3DMax and Unity will recognize it perfectly fine but Blender won't.

Graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti,
Processor is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 3501 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

Dunno what else is needed but let me know, I'll find it.